# Lentitud en sitio wordpress al activar el plugin de Mercadopago

Tags: api, mercadopago, woocommerce, plugin

Quería solicitar ayuda, ya que estoy creando una tienda de compra online para un cliente en wordpress. Tengo instalado woocommerce y el plugin de mercadopago con las versiones que muestro en la imagen adjunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema bastante grave, y es el siguiente. Cuando activo la aplicación de ustedes el carrito de compra se vuelve demasiado lento, imposible de trabajar y muy lento en caso de que se quieran hacer compras online.
Mi cliente es una librería bastante grande la cual necesita vender con Mercadopago, pero de esta forma resulta imposible. El sitio web esta alojado en un hosting de Argentina. Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto? Existe la posibilidad de que se pueda realizar los pagos a través de un link externo o alguna forma que no tenga que instalar este plugin el cual me vuelve todo tan lento?

Espero puedan brindarme una solución.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasa lo mismo, lo que me dice mi proveedor de hosting es:

**> Por los registros vemos que lo que demora mucho es la conexión con:

> api.mercadopago.com Es necesario validar con dicho servidor si hay
>   alguna restricción con la conexión. Saludos**

Apenas ponerte de acuerdo con los de api de mercadopago